# Flann index in OpenCV Java API

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0, knn, flann

How do I create a Flann index with OpenCV in Java?

I am trying to do a KNN search of feature descriptors. I cannot find the equivalent class in Java API. Or is the official Java binding incomplete?

The C++ class is documented here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html#flann-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate Flann matcher in Java using this construction:

```
FlannBasedMatcher matcher = FlannBasedMatcher.create();
```

Please ensure you are using OpenCV 3.2 or higher version.

Answer (score 0):

To the people who have same question as me : I ended up using JavaCV, which seems to be much closer to the C++ API.